# Firebase login error message not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uialertcontroller

When the user logs in with correct credentials SVProgressHUD shows and dismisses correctly, and the user segues correctly to the main home screen. However when the password or email is incorrect the SVProgressHUD shows endlessly and no alert is popping up.

```
@IBAction func signInButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    let email = emailText.text!.lowercased()
    let finalEmail = email.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passwordText.text!

    if finalEmail.isEmpty || password.isEmpty {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Please fill in all the fields.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {
      SVProgressHUD.show()

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

            if error == nil {
                if let user = user {
                    print("\(user.displayName!) has been signed in")

                   SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        //            self.enter()
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInHome", sender: nil)

                }else{
                     SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                   print("error")
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Low Blow!", message: "incorrect credentials", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


                    print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case error is `null` you forget to dismiss the `SVProgressHUD`

checkout this code

```
@IBAction func signInButton(_ sender: Any) 
{

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    let email = emailText.text!.lowercased()
    let finalEmail = email.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passwordText.text!

    if finalEmail.isEmpty || password.isEmpty 
    {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Please fill in all the fields.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else 
    {
        SVProgressHUD.show()

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) 
        { 
            (user, error) in

            if error == nil 
            {
                if let user = user 
                {
                    print("\(user.displayName!) has been signed in")
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInHome", sender: nil)
                }
                else
                {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    print("error")
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Low Blow!", message: "incorrect credentials", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```